# Sql TOP 1 query is performing very slow when table has thousands of records?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Sql TOP 1 query is performing very slow when table has thousands  of records?

```
select Top 1 * from AA011 WHERE order By datadate DESC
```

Comment: can you post the query atleast

Comment: View the query plan - perhaps it's doing a table scan.

Comment: Do you have an index on `datadate` field ?

Comment: Try to *avoid* using `SELECT *` if ever possible - try `SELECT TOP (1) (list of columns)` for only those columns you *really need* - otherwise you'll almost always get a clustered index scan (= table scan) and try to have a **covering index** that contains all the columns you need (as *included* columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look to the execution plan of your query.

It is very likely that you will see something like table/clustered index scan and then sort. This means you have no index built on `datadate` field of your table - so SQL server has to retrieve all the data from the table and sort it to get your top 1 value.

If you will build index on this column, SQL server will use this index rather than retrieving all the data and sort it - so it will greatly increase performance.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `clustered index` on `datadate` column which should speed up the process

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX AA011_datadate ON AA011(datadate DESC)
```

Comment: I have Created clustered index on datadate column, so I have to use non clustered index on datadate ?

Comment: Go with clustered index as data is physically stored in index order

Comment: @MohanSingh It depends on your table structure and usage of it. Usually it is not so good idea to have clustered index on fields other than autoincremented ID /primary key field. Clustered index defines order of data being physically stored, so in the case of clustered index on `datadate` if you will insert into your table records not in the order of `datadate` - SQL server will resort whole table each time, so it can reduce performance of insert.